# Boxplot and violin plot with multiple categories

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot, violin-plot

I have a chemical database. It contains the chemical analysis of different elements in 4 different categories.

I made a simplified version of what my df looks like, in reality, it has more elements.

[image]

I want to plot boxplots and violinplots comparing each element of each category. Something like this:

[image]

Would you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seaborn expects [long-form data](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-data) where each row corresponds to one observation.

1. [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) the data by `Category`:

   ```
   melted = df.melt('Category', var_name='Element', value_name='Concentration')

   #    Category  Element  Concentration
   # 0         A       Au         0.1000
   # 1         A       Au         0.1500
   # 2         A       Au         0.4000
   # 3         B       Au         0.1000
   # ...
   # 10        D       Au         1.0000
   # 11        A       Ag         1.0000
   # ...
   # 20        D       Ag        40.0000
   # 21        D       Ag        56.0000
   ```
2. Use this `melted` dataframe with [`boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) and [`violinplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html):

   ```
   sns.boxplot(data=melted, x='Element', y='Concentration', hue='Category')
   ```

   ```
   sns.violinplot(data=melted, x='Element', y='Concentration', hue='Category')
   ```